# Improving the efficiency (memory/time) of the following python code

Tags: python

I have to read about 300 files to create an association with the following piece of code. Given the association, I have to read them all in memory.

```
  with util.open_input_file(f) as f_in:
     for l in f_in:
        w = l.split(',')
        dfm = dk.to_key((idx, i, int(w[0]), int(w[1]))) <-- guaranteed to be unique for each line in file.
        cands  = w[2].split(':')
        for cand in cands:
          tmp_data.setdefault(cand, []).append(dfm)
```

Then I need to write out the data structure above in this format:

```
k1, v1:v2,v3....
k2, v2:v5,v6...
```

I use the following code:

```
    # Sort / join values.
    cand2dfm_data = {}
    for k,v in tmp_data.items():
        cand2dfm_data[k] = ':'.join(map(str, sorted(v, key=int)))
    tmp_data = {}

    # Write cand2dfm CSV file.
    with util.open_output_file(cand2dfm_file) as f_out:
        for k in sorted(cand2dfm_data.keys()):
            f_out.write('%s,%s\n' % (k, cand2dfm_data[k]))
```

Since I have to process a significant number of files, I'm observing two problems:

1. The memory used to store *tmp_data* is very big. In my use case, processing 300 files, it is using 42GB.
2. Writing out the CSV file is taking a long time. This is because I'm calling write() on each item() (about 2.2M). Furthermore, the output stream is using gzip compressor to save disk space.

In my use case, the numbers are guaranteed to be 32-bit unsigned.

Question:

1. To achieve memory reduction, I think it will be better to use a 32-bit int to store the data. Should I use ctypes.c_int() to store the values in the dict() (right now they are strings) or is there a better way?
2. For speeding up the writing, should I write to a StringIO object and then dump that to a file or is there a better way?
3. Alternatively, maybe there is a better way to accomplish the above logic without reading everything in memory?

Comment: If your code is running without errors, a better place to ask could be [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few thoughts.

1. Currently you are duplicating data multiple times in the memory.
   You are loading it for the first time into `tmp_data`, then copying everything into `cand2dfm_data` and then creating list of keys by calling `sorted(cand2dfm_data.keys())`.

   To reduce memory usage:

   - Get rid of the `tmp_data`, parse and write your data directly to the `cand2dfm_data`
   - Make `cand2dfm_data` a list of tuples, not the dict
   - Use `cand2dfm_data.sort(...)` instead of `sorted(cand2dfm_data)` to avoid creation of a new list
2. To speed up processing:

   - Convert keys into ints to improve sorting performance (this will reduce memory usage as well)
   - Write data to disk in chunks, like 100 or 500 or 1000 records in one go, this should improve I\O performance a bit
3. Use [profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to find other performance bottlenecks
4. If with above optimizations memory footprint will still be too large then consider using disk backed storage for storing and sorting temporary data, e.g. SQLite

Comment: On top of that, if you are working with numerical data, than why not use NumPy or such? It will give a tremendous boost in performance and memory-efficiency.